# Ion producing null result

Tags: android, android-ion

I am having trouble receiving data from my API call using [Ion](https://github.com/koush/ion). I am working through an [Udacity tutorial](https://github.com/udacity/Sunshine-Version-2/blob/f18784f490e71f6816fa1fe5fb9b5dafff38b93d/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/sunshine/app/ForecastFragment.java) that uses a bunch of boilerplate code to receive the data from the API. I wanted to go a different route - primarily to learn - and use Ion to make my network request.

Things I have done:

1. Altered the context argument of Ion call
2. Validated the url of the API call in an internet browser
3. Placed Ion result inside an if statement to prevent app from crashing if result is null
4. Added setLogging to Ion request
5. Added Network Permission in AndroidManifest

Unfortunately, I am still receiving nothing in the Android Monitor.

```
package com.example.android.sunshine.app;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.koushikdutta.async.future.FutureCallback;
import com.koushikdutta.ion.Ion;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Chasen on 1/7/2017.
 */

public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    private ArrayAdapter<String> forecastAdapter;
    public static final String LOG_TAG = ForecastFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    public static final String baseURL = "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London";
    public static final String api_key = "&APPID=" + BuildConfig.OPEN_WEATHER_API_KEY;

    public ForecastFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_view_forecast);

        ArrayList<String> forecastEntries = new ArrayList<String>();
        forecastEntries.add("Today - Sunny - 88/63");
        forecastEntries.add("Tomorrow - Foggy - 70/46");
        forecastEntries.add("Wed - Cloudy - 72/63");
        forecastEntries.add("Thurs - Rainy - 64/52");
        forecastEntries.add("Fri - Foggy - 70/46");
        forecastEntries.add("Sat - Sunny - 76/68");

        forecastAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(rootView.getContext()
                ,R.layout.list_item_forecast
                ,R.id.list_item_forecast_textview
                ,forecastEntries);

        /*
        {"coord":{"lon":-0.13,"lat":51.51}
        ,"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10d"}]
        ,"base":"stations"
        ,"main":{"temp":281.82,"pressure":1012,"humidity":93,"temp_min":281.15,"temp_max":282.15}
        ,"visibility":10000
        ,"wind":{"speed":7.7,"deg":190}
        ,"clouds":{"all":75},"dt":1483969800
        ,"sys":{"type":1,"id":5187
        ,"message":0.2086
        ,"country":"GB","sunrise":1483948990,"sunset":1483978386},"id":2643743,"name":"London","cod":200}

         */

        listView.setAdapter(forecastAdapter);
        return rootView;
    }

    private static void logResult(String result) {
        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, json.toString());
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.wtf(LOG_TAG, e);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.forecastfragment, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();
        if(id == R.menu.forecastfragment) {
            Ion.with(this)
                    .load(baseURL.concat(api_key))
                    .setLogging(LOG_TAG, Log.DEBUG)
                    .asString()
                    .setCallback(new FutureCallback<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(Exception e, String result) {
                            if(result != null) {
                                Log.v(LOG_TAG, result);
                            }
                            //logResult(result);
                        }
                    });
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to add http:// to the baseURL.